# How to Fix Error In SQL Query

Tags: sql, mysql

Error
SQL query: Documentation

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_vehicle_details 
INNER JOIN tbl_user, tbl_ride 
ON `tbl_vehicle_details`.`v_u_id` = `tbl_user`.`u_id` AND 
   `tbl_ride`.`r_v_id` =`tbl_vehicle_details`.`v_id` 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ON `tbl_vehicle_details`.`v_u_id` = `tbl_user`.`u_id` AND
>   `tbl_ride`.`r_v_id` =    ' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing implicit with explicit join syntax. Try this instead:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_vehicle_details 
INNER JOIN tbl_user
ON `tbl_vehicle_details`.`v_u_id` = `tbl_user`.`u_id`
INNER JOIN tbl_ride 
ON `tbl_ride`.`r_v_id` =`tbl_vehicle_details`.`v_id` 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

**Note:** Usage of `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` clause results in an arbitrary selection of records as there is no inherent order in an SQL table.